# Selenium with Sikuli4Net not able to compare image against full screen launched from chrome driver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, sikuli

I would like to compare images I have captured using Snippet tool that will be used to compare against the current window or screen launched from Selenium chrome driver.  My code is below

```
 [TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    private IWebDriver webdriver = null;
    private APILauncher launcher = new APILauncher(true);
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        launcher.Start();
        GetWebDriver("http://www.google.com");
        Screen screen = new Screen();
        //Pattern googleSearchScreenPattern = new Pattern(@"C:\Users\amaddox\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\SikuliDemo\Images\GoogleSearch.PNG");
        //Pattern googleSearchScreenPattern = new Pattern(@"C:\Users\amaddox\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\SikuliDemo\Images\Espn.PNG");
        //Pattern googleSearchScreenPattern = new Pattern(@"C:\Users\amaddox\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\SikuliDemo\Images\Text.PNG");
        Pattern googleSearchScreenPattern = new Pattern(@"C:\Users\amaddox\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\SikuliDemo\Images\GoogleFailureSearchImage2.PNG");
        //screen.Wait(googleSearchScreenPattern, 10);



        Assert.IsTrue(screen.Exists(googleSearchScreenPattern, 10));


        launcher.Stop();
        CloseDriver();



    }
    private void GetWebDriver(string url)
    {
        webdriver = new ChromeDriver();
        webdriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        webdriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        webdriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

    }
    private void CloseDriver()
    {
        webdriver.Quit();
    }
}
```

I am using Visual Studio and I have imported all the nuget packages for Selenium and Chrome in my unit test project.  The test basically navigates to the chrome main page and then I am trying to compare the images below with what I see on the screen launched from chrome driver.  The tests keeps passing, but there are differences between what I see and the screen captures.  How can I get sikuli to match exactly using C#.Net and selenium.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The way you use the Pattern it matches the image up to 70% (default).

You can try with higher precision. E.g.:

```
var imagePattern = new Pattern(@"C:\Users\image.png", 0.99);
```

The number is Double where 1 = 100% and 0.1 equals 10% similarity.